# Deriving `\beta_1` in OLS

Tags: econometrics, regression

I'm studying for an Econometrics exam and going over an old lecture slide (see picture).
In it the lecturer is deriving `\beta_1` in a basic OLS regression with one variable.

I understand everything up to equation 10 and I am able to calcualte eq.11, but I do not understand *why* the additions/subtractions need to be made in eq. 11. From what I can tell `\beta_1` in 10 is not equal to `\beta_1` in 11?

Can someone explain why the calcutations are made in this way? And is equation 10 equal to 11?
This is very important for me to know because deriving `\beta_1` has been a question in basically every exam.

[image]

**EDIT:** I realize now that this question should probably be posted on the statistics-SE instead. I am not eligible to migrate questions so I would appreciate the help of a moderator for doing this. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working backwards from the numerator in 11 to the numerator in 10, we have:

$$\begin{align}\tag{11}\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\bar{X})(Y_i-\bar{Y})
&=\sum_{i=1}^n (X_iY_i-X_i\bar{Y}-\bar{X}Y_i+\bar{X}\bar{Y})\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n X_iY_i- \sum_{i=1}^nX_i\bar{Y}- \sum_{i=1}^n\bar{X}Y_i+\sum_{i=1}^n\bar{X}\bar{Y}\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n X_iY_i- \bar{Y}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i-\bar{X} \sum_{i=1}^nY_i+n\bar{X}\bar{Y}\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n X_iY_i- \bar{Y}(n\bar{X})-\bar{X} (n\bar{Y})+n\bar{X}\bar{Y}\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n X_iY_i- n\bar{X}\bar{Y}-n\bar{X}\bar{Y}+n\bar{X}\bar{Y}\tag{B}\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n X_iY_i- n\bar{X}\bar{Y}\tag{A}\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n X_iY_i- n \left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i\right)\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nY_i\right)\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n X_iY_i- \frac{1}{n}\left(\sum_{i=1}^nX_i\right)\left(\sum_{i=1}^nY_i\right) \tag{10}\\
\end{align}$$

The term $\bar{X}\sum_{i=1}^nY_i=n\bar{X}\bar{Y}$ is added and subtracted when going from $(\text{A})$ to $(\text{B})$.

Comment: Thank you! It took me a while to get, even whith your step-by-step solution. Now onto the denominator! :D